# C++ cassandra client select int value

Tags: c++, select, int, cassandra

I'm trying to select an integer value but I can't
This is my code:

```
cassandra_socket = boost::shared_ptr<TSocket>(new TSocket(host, port));
cassandra_transport = boost::shared_ptr<TFramedTransport>(new TFramedTransport(cassandra_socket));
protocol = boost::shared_ptr<TBinaryProtocol>(new TBinaryProtocol(cassandra_transport));
cassandra_client = new CassandraClient(protocol);
try {
    cassandra_transport->open();
    cassandra_client->set_keyspace("MPS");
    ColumnOrSuperColumn csc;
    ColumnPath cpath;
    cpath.column_family.assign("SubmitResposes_count");
    /* This is required - thrift 'feature' */
    cpath.__isset.column = true;
    cpath.column = "Counter";
    cassandra_client->get(csc, "1", cpath,org::apache::cassandra::ConsistencyLevel::ONE);
    cout << "Value read is '" << csc.column.value << "'..." << endl;
}
catch (NotFoundException &nf) {
    FORCE_TRACE(0, "NOT FOUND EXCEPTION ERROR: %s", nf.what());
} catch (InvalidRequestException &re) {
    FORCE_TRACE(0, "INVALID REQUEST ERROR: %s", re.why);
} catch (TException &tx) {
    FORCE_TRACE(0, "TEEXCEPTION ERROR: %s", tx.what());
}
```

it gives me this exception:
InvalidRequest ERROR: Expected 4 or 0 byte int (1)

& this is the table I've created:

```
create table SubmitResposes_count(
    ID int primary key,
    Counter bigint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your key is an int:

```
ID int primary key,
```

but you are querying using a string key:

```
cassandra_client->get(csc, "1", cpath,org::apache::cassandra::ConsistencyLevel::ONE);
                           ^^^
```

Cassandra is trying to validate your string as an int, which is causing this exception.

Comment: the function "get" only takes string how can i query with integer key?

Comment: You appear to be using an old thrift spec. The [current version](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/interface/cassandra.thrift) uses binary keys.  Have you considered using a high-level client instead of Thrift?  Using Thrift directly is not recommended unless you have a specific reason to do so.